# Prevent parent directory file listing except default index files and avoid redirecting to Error 403 using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have created a `.htaccess` file (*given bellow*) to prevent parent directory file listing, except default `index` files. Also, I have created a custom redirection file `illegal_access.php` for **Error 403**.

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.sitename.edu/illegal_access.php
Options -Indexes
```

To capture the site activity, I have included `log.php` inside all PHP files (including `illegal_access.php`). Everything works fine.

But, In log file, for each parent directory access with `index.php` file it captures both `index.php` file name and `illegal_access.php` file name. For example:

If I open the site http://www.sitename.edu, the log file captures both
http://www.sitename.edu/ and http://www.sitename.edu/illegal_access.php URLs.

Is it possible to solve this issue, without excluding the `log.php` file inside the `illegal_access.php` file? Because, I want to capture the illegal access activity too.